# Removing prewritten fields in new calendar events

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

I mainly want to remove the ''location'' field in my calendar but it seems to be locked somehow. I need a way to remove or hide it. From what i have found all the web and designer allows me to do is change its description....

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem. All I had to do was simply to not remove the fields entirely, but from the view that is used when a new event is to be created. This is done in SPD.